# Making solution for Project Euler more efficient

Tags: java, prime-factoring

Originally, I was having some issues getting this code to function, but after a little tweaking I got it debugged and ready to go.

I have gone through several revisions of this program. I started with integer values only to find that the number was too large to fit into an int. I then changed to BigIntegers, which proved to be a hassle, but workable. From there, I switched to longs (as should have done from the beginning) and cut the runtime of my code 8-fold (or more).

Here's the code as it is now:

```
long qNum = 600851475143L;

for (long i = qNum - 1L; i * i >= qNum; i -= 2L)
    if (qNum % i == 0 && isPrime(i)) {
        System.out.println("Solution:" + i); // for debugging
        return i;
    }
    else
        System.out.println(i);// for debugging

return 0L;
```

And

```
public static boolean isPrime(long num) {
    // unnecessary if statement for this problem (b/c of for loop), but useful for others 
    if (num % 2 == 0)
        return false;

    for (long i = 3; i * i <= num; i += 2)
        if (num % i == 0)
            return false;

    return true;
}
```

It's been running for multiple hours and it still hasn't found anything. I saw online that solving this puzzle the typical way is like parsing 560GB of data =/.

Any tips for speeding this up?

Many thanks,

Justian

**EDIT:**

Optimized code:

```
public static long greatestPrimeFactor(ArrayList<Long> factors, long num) {
    for (long i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(num); i++) {
        if (num % i == 0) {
            factors.add(i);
            return greatestPrimeFactor(factors, num / i);
        }
    }

    for (int i = factors.size()-1; i > 0; i--)
        if (isPrime(factors.get(i)))
            return num;

    return 0;
}
```

AND

```
public static boolean isPrime(long num) {
if (num % 2 == 0)
    return false;

for (long i = 3; i * i <= num; i += 2)
    if (num % i == 0)
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

RUN WITH

```
greatestPrimeFactor(new ArrayList<Long>(), 600851475143L);
```

Comment: Tip: for `isPrime`, you can start at the square root of the number instead of 3.

Comment: What is the question from Project Euler?  Find the largest prime smaller than 600851475143?

Comment: @jtbandes: I go from 3 to square root. How does this help me? | @KLee1: Largest prime factor- correct.

Comment: Ah, never mind, I missed that.

Comment: @jtbandes: All's well :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My solution hits in less than a hundredth of a second.  Each time you find a divisor of the number, divide the number by that divisor and start again.  The highest number you divide by is your target.

Comment: I think this is what basically I did, if I remember correctly.

Comment: @user30997: Finished it. Many thanks! See finalized code above. Any other last-minute suggestions?

Comment: Last-minute suggestion?  If you're on Euler Project #3, give up before it sucks your life away!  =]  I think I had too much fun (and spent too much time on) EP problems...

Comment: @user30997: I'm very careful about getting too hooked on stuff like this. The only comments I made on this question were the brief seconds I was on the computer (I've been busy with other things). It's very fun, though :). Great practice. By the way, the new code runs at 0-1 milliseconds, just as you promised ;).

Answer (score 3):

You are doing too many unnecessary things.  Here's a simpler solution:

```
long greatestFactor(long n) {
    long p = 0;
    for (long k = 2; k * k <= n; k++)
        while (n % k == 0) {
            n /= k;
            p = k;
        }
    if (n > 1)
        p = n;
    return p;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to test every number for whether or not it is prime. You see this, so you only test every ODD number (well, and 2). You can take this further! Construct a table of the first few million primes quickly, and only test against those. You'll go a LOT faster, with a very small overhead.

Edit: Here's what I was talking about. It's quite straightforward. Notice how I only compare the values to already computed primes. Once you've computed a fair number of them (say, the first 10000000 primes) start doing your search based on on the +2 method like you are. Keep in mind that most of them are going to get caught early because you're skipping unnecessary numbers. You don't need to test 15,25,35,45,55, etc, because you already tested 5. That in and of itself is going to cull about 20% of your tests, which easily accounts for the overhead of calculating the first few million numbers.

Sample output

```
C:\files\j\misc>java sandbox2
resized to 200
resized to 400
resized to 800
resized to 1600
resized to 3200
resized to 6400
resized to 12800
resized to 25600
resized to 51200
resized to 102400
resized to 204800
resized to 409600
resized to 819200
664579 primes in 18 seconds. Last prime was 9999991

C:\files\j\misc>
```

Sample code:

```
public class sandbox2 {
    static int[] primes = new int[100]; // where the primes really are
    static int count = 0;
    static long mostRecentPrime;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        addPrime(2); // give it a couple to start
        addPrime(3);
        addPrime(5);
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for(long i = 7; i < 10000000; i++) { // all primes less than 10M
            if(isPrime(i)) addPrime(i);            
        }        
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long time = (end-start) / 1000;
        System.out.println(count + " primes in " + time + " seconds. Last prime was " + mostRecentPrime);
    }    
    public static boolean isPrime(long i) {
        long max = (long)(Math.sqrt(i))+1;
        for(int pos = 0; primes[pos] < max && pos < primes.length; pos++) {
            long prime = (long)(primes[pos]);
            if(i % prime == 0) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }    
    public static void addPrime(long p) {
        mostRecentPrime = p;
        if(count == primes.length) { // resize if necessary
            int size = primes.length * 2;
            int[] newprimes = new int[size];
            System.arraycopy(primes, 0, newprimes, 0, primes.length);
            primes = newprimes;
            System.out.println("resized to " + primes.length);
        }
        primes[(int)count] = (int)p;
        count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: @glowcoder: I already test only odds and I don't know how to generate a few million primes "quickly" =/. I know there's a method with long numbers, but it'd still take far too long.

Comment: I'll edit my answer with some sample code I've toyed with in the past. You may need to adapt it - one moment

Comment: I'm also adding another answer unrelated to what I'm doing in this answer. Pay attention to that.

Comment: @glowcoder: Please, do feel free to add it :) If your solution is better, I will change my answer.

Comment: Something came up (I am at work :) ) and I won't be able to tonight, or perhaps later. It has to do with your start... you have an odd number, then you take int i = num - 1, which means i is an even number. Now, if you're constantly `-=2`ing an even number, you'll always get an even number, and you'll never get a prime... But I didn't investiate much further.

Comment: @glowcoder: You're right about my start, but it didn't matter because the input was hard-coded. It was flawed, though.

Answer (score 0):

In python, you can just calculate all the prime factors and then use the max function, like so:

```
def calc_prime_factors(n,i=2,result=[]):
  while i<=n:
    while n%i!=0:
      i+=1
    result.append(i)
    if n!=1:
      n,i=n/i,2
    else:
      break
  return result

print max(calc_prime_factors(600851475143))
```